# creating multiple global objects in java-script rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an instance object as `@cameras`in my cameras controller's `map` method and am getting few values from it for my cause as

```
+    @cameras = load_user_cameras(true, false)
+    @map_data = []
+    @cameras.each do |camera|
+      @map_data[@map_data.length] = [
+        camera["name"],
+        camera["id"],
+        camera["owner"],
+        camera["is_online"],
+        camera["is_public"],
+        camera["vendor_id"],
+        camera["location"],
+        camera["vendor_name"],
+        thumbnail_url(camera)
+      ]
+    end
```

And I want to do something as in my `map.html.erb`

```
  window.Evercam.Camera = {
    id: '<%= @map_data['id'] %>',
    name:'<%= @map_data['name'] %>',
    is_online: <%= @map_data['is_online'] %>,
    vendor_id: '<%= @map_data['vendor_id'] %>',
 }
```

But for multiple objects not only single `Evercam.Camera` but `Evercam.Cameras` as there are going to be multiple records in `@map_data` So I want to create a global object as `Evercam.Cameras` to which i can totally assign the whole object `@map_data`? Is it possible.. anyhelp will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this alot harder than it needs to be, in Rails you can use the `to_json` http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json.

In the controller use `map` it will work on any enumerable and is doing the same thing you are doing but is faster and more reliable. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map.

```
@cameras = load_user_cameras(true, false)
@map_data = @cameras.map do |camaras|
    ### This will be turned into json, so make sure the key is what you need later when you retrieve it in Javascript.
    id: camera['id'],
    name: camera['name']
    ### AND SO ON ... 
end
```

In the erb, the `to_json` method will take your enumerable and turn it into a json object.

```
window.Evercam.Cameras = <%= @map_data.to_json %>;
```

Comment: ` syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end name: camera["name"],`

Comment: adding curly braces to map object in controller worked but this is not working `window.Evercam.Cameras = <%= @map_data.to_json %>`

Comment: i am getting this error in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`